# unfortunately app_name has stopped

Tags: android

i have developed an app for navigation from 1st activity to second activity and from 2nd activity to 3rd activity . when i run my app it navigates from 1st to 2nd activity but not from 2nd to 3rd activity instead it shows "unfortunately app has stopped". i have posted my code and log cat errors.help me pls. to recover from errors.plsss pls help me out.

### 1st xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:text="REGISTER" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="LOGIN" />
```

### 2nd xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="USER NAME"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="REGISTRATION FORM"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="PASSWORD"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="E-MAIL ID"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:text="ADDRESS"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="SUBMIT" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="CANCEL" />
```

### 3rd xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="16dp"
    android:layout_y="238dp"
    android:text="DELIVERY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="4dp"
    android:layout_y="141dp"
    android:text="YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:context=".WelActivity" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="90dp"
    android:layout_y="66dp"
    android:text="WELCOME"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="178dp"
    android:layout_y="238dp"
    android:text="CARRY OUT" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="121dp"
    android:layout_y="313dp"
    android:text="DINE IN" />
```

```
// java code
```

### 1st activity

```
package com.example.pizza;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addButtonClickEventListener();
    }

        public void addButtonClickEventListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Context context = MainActivity.this;
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent (context,RegActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }   

        });
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

### 2nd activity

```
package com.example.pizza;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class RegActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancestate)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstancestate);
        setContentView(R.layout.regfrm);
        addButtonOnClickEventListener();

    }

    private void addButtonOnClickEventListener() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final Context context = RegActivity.this;
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent (context,WelActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }   

        });
        }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

### 3rd activity

```
package com.example.pizza;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class WelActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancestate)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstancestate);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
        addButtonOnClickEventListener();

    }

    private void addButtonOnClickEventListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        final Context context = WelActivity.this;
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent (context,OrderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }   

        });
        }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

### manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pizza"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pizza.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




        <activity android:name="com.example.pizza.RegActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.pizza.WelActivity"></activity>


         </application>


</manifest>
```

### logcat errors

```
02-12 19:21:05.430: I/Choreographer(820): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 19:21:05.930: D/gralloc_goldfish(820): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-12 19:21:17.420: I/Choreographer(820): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 19:21:22.180: I/Choreographer(820): Skipped 128 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 19:21:27.340: I/Choreographer(820): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 19:21:27.920: D/AndroidRuntime(820): Shutting down VM
02-12 19:21:27.920: W/dalvikvm(820): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a96b90)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820): Process: com.example.pizza, PID: 820
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pizza/com.example.pizza.WelActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at com.example.pizza.WelActivity.addButtonOnClickEventListener(WelActivity.java:27)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at com.example.pizza.WelActivity.onCreate(WelActivity.java:19)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-12 19:21:28.020: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  ... 11 more
02-12 19:21:32.050: I/Process(820): Sending signal. PID: 820 SIG: 9
02-12 19:21:34.340: I/Choreographer(837): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 19:21:34.430: D/gralloc_goldfish(837): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-12 03:30:08.860: D/gralloc_goldfish(1119): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-12 03:30:20.660: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 179 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 03:30:22.400: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 03:30:23.010: D/AndroidRuntime(1119): Shutting down VM
02-12 03:30:23.010: W/dalvikvm(1119): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a96b90)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): Process: com.example.pizza, PID: 1119
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pizza/com.example.pizza.WelActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.example.pizza.WelActivity.addButtonOnClickEventListener(WelActivity.java:27)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.example.pizza.WelActivity.onCreate(WelActivity.java:19)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-12 03:30:23.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     ... 11 more
02-12 03:30:26.870: I/Process(1119): Sending signal. PID: 1119 SIG: 9
02-12 03:30:30.260: I/Choreographer(1144): Skipped 212 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 03:30:30.380: D/gralloc_goldfish(1144): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you start the 3rd activity?
Looking at the logcat, the problem is with the call to this class: com.example.pizza.WelActivity

Comment: you are having a NullPointerException in line 27 of WelActivity

Comment: That may generally cause due to their manifest file. show us?

Comment: Code and logcat is included, its just 1 big code-field

Comment: @TimCastelijns oh, found it ;)

Comment: which is 27 line in WelActivity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No id found named `button5` in your 3rd Activity layout.

```
Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
```

Change the id in your activity class.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of `button5` id is not getting from its layout file.